# Bash script won't start in background with post-execute-command

Tags: php, linux, bash, background-process

Bash waiting for signal to end

**Logic:**

1. start execution of bash script that must start A.php in back ground and redirect stdout
    to log file or /dev/null
2. on A.php success execute B.php
3. on error execute B.php with A.php error as argument

But, bash start A.php and waiting...

```
#ps -aux
root     27647  0.0  0.0  13336   652 pts/0    S+   11:36   0:00 /bin/bash /var/www/scripts/bgluncher.sh -c php /var/scripts/A.php -l /var/log/A.log -p B.php
root     27648  0.7  0.2 332396 87544 pts/0    S+   11:36   0:02 php /var/scripts/A.php
```

**bash:**

```
#!/bin/bash
COMM=''
POST_CMD=''
LOG=0

while getopts ":l:c:p:" arg; do
    case "${arg}" in
        c)
            COMM=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        l)
            LOG=1
            LOG_File=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        p)
            POST_CMD=${OPTARG}
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${COMM}" ]; then
   echo `date` ' ERROR: [bgluncher.sh] -c argument is empty ' >> ${LOG_File}
else
    if [ ${LOG} -eq 1 ] ; then
        ${COMM} >> ${LOG_File} && ${POST_CMD} || ${POST_CMD}/error=$2 &
        echo $!
    else
        ${COMM} >> /dev/null && ${POST_CMD} || ${POST_CMD}/error=$2 &
        echo $!
    fi
fi

exit
```

To be or not to be and what an error I has made?

Answer (score 0):

`$2` is the second command line argument (php), not the exit code of COMM, use `$?` for that.
And you probably want a space rather than a / after ${POST_CMD}; `B.php error=2` rather than `B.php/error=2`

Comment: Ok!
Thanks!
That was one of the problems '$?'
Actually php scripts wait for /arg1=val1/arg2=val2.
But bash still waiting to end A.php and don't send it in background